# Google Maps Api 3 - fitBounds on Visible Markers doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've a problem with a **Google Maps** in a website.

By using PHP, JS and Google Maps Api 3 I'am able to generate a Map with various Markers, selecting them from a database MySql. Every one has a category ('Turismo' and 'Mangiare'), so with two simple functions and two checkbox (in a HTML form) I can Hide or Show every category.

The problem is that I need to fitBounds only the VISIBLE Markers in the Map every time I click on a checkbox.
So, I'm trying with a function found here in stackoverflow, but I'm not able to make it work. :(
**The console give me an error of "undefined"** at this line *"map.fitBounds(bounds);"*. Maybe it is related to the global variable "map"!

*Here is my **Script** code:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

  var markers = [                           
                    <? for ($i=0; $i<count($elementi); $i++) { ?>   
                    ['<?=$elementi[$i]['elem']?>', <?=$elementi[$i]['e_coord']?>, 'marker/mk_<?=$elementi[$i]['icona']?>.png', '<?=$i+1?>', "turismo"],
                    <? } ?>
                    <? for ($i=0; $i<count($recensioni_mangiare); $i++) { ?>    
                    ['<?=$recensioni_mangiare[$i]['Prod']?>', <?=$recensioni_mangiare[$i]['map_lat']?>, <?=$recensioni_mangiare[$i]['map_lon']?>, 'marker/mk_mangiare.png', '<?=$i+1?>', "mangiare"],
                    <? } ?>             
  ];
 var map;
 var gmarkers = [];
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        maxWidth: 400
                    });




function initialize() {
                        var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: <?=$itinerario['zoom']?>,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$itinerario['coord']?>)
                    };

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        maxWidth: 400
                    });
                    var marker, i;
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
                        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                        bounds.extend(pos);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pos,
                            map: map,
                            icon: markers[i][3],
                            title: markers[i][0],
                            tipo: markers[i][5], 
                            visible: true
                        });
                        marker.tipologia = markers[i][5];
                        gmarkers.push(marker);                          
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][4]);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, i));
                    }   
                    show('turismo');
                    hide('mangiare');               
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    }

 function show(type) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].tipologia == type) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById(type+"box").checked = true;
  }

  function hide(type) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].tipologia == type) {
       gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById(type+"box").checked = false;
    infowindow.close();
  }

  function boxclick(box,tipo) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(tipo);
    } else {
      hide(tipo);
    }
    fitBoundsToVisibleMarkers();
  }

  function fitBoundsToVisibleMarkers() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);
    for (var i in gmarkers) {
        if(gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
            bounds.extend(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
        }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}   

</script>
```

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the map to the global scope. In your initialize function change

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

to

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

since you are already initializing the variable map into the global scope above. By adding the 'var' you are limiting the scope of the map object to the initialize function